# REPLACE NULL IN SSIS Derived Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

I have an SSIS package which transfers data from SAS to SQL Server. I'm creating a derived column but cannot get the `REPLACENULL` feature to work. I am receiving the error

> "Invalid character value for cast specification"

which I am sure is because of NULL values in the source. Here is my current derived column expression:

```
REPLACENULL(DATEADD("d",(DT_I8)AuthEndDate,(DT_DATE)"1960-01-01"),0)
```

The `REPLACENULL` function isn't working here. Any way that this can be done? I am using SSIS 2008. Thanks.

Comment: First off, `REPLACENULL()` needs to be around the source column of `AuthEndDate` (not the entire expression), but I'm also pretty sure you cannot convert a date to a bigint (assuming AuthEndDate is in fact a date).  What are you trying to do here exactly?

Comment: Tried that and still getting the error. The reason I'm converting the date as is is because the data is coming from SAS. It transfers perfectly when I try it on a column without NULL. The DataType for the column is [DT_STR].

Comment: OK and if AuthEndDate is in fact NULL, what value do you want downstream?

Comment: I would like it to just be blank or a 0

Answer (score 1):

Since you want blank/0 to flow downstream you need an `if`, not a `replacenull()`

Please note blank/0 in SQL Server writes as 1900-01-01, blank/0 are not valid date values, so it defaults to this.  The only other option is NULL.

This should work if the destination is a datetime column:

```
ISNULL(AuthEndDate) ? (DT_DATE)0 : DATEADD("d",(DT_I8)AuthEndDate,(DT_DATE)"1960-01-01")
```

If you opt to write NULL instead of 1900-01-01, you can do this:

```
ISNULL(AuthEndDate) ? NULL(DT_DATE) : DATEADD("d",(DT_I8)AuthEndDate,(DT_DATE)"1960-01-01")
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use one of the following expressions:

```
DATEADD("d",(DT_I8)REPLACENULL([AuthEndDate],0),(DT_DATE)"1960-01-01")
```

OR

```
ISNULL([AuthEndDate]) ? (DT_DATE)"1960-01-01" : DATEADD("d",(DT_I8)AuthEndDate,(DT_DATE)"1960-01-01")
```

*Note that  you cannot use a logic that can return multiple datatypes, both cases must return on datatype (`DT_DATE`)*

Answer (score 0):

If the source is returning NULLs, then try a REPLACENULL at AuthEndDate rather than after the calculations. The statement you have will try to do calculations with NULLs which is never good.

So...

```
REPLACENULL(DATEADD("d",REPLACENULL((DT_I8)AuthEndDate,0),(DT_DATE)"1960-01-01"),0)
```

**Edit - replacenull and then apply conversion:**

```
DATEADD("d",(DT_I8)REPLACENULL(AuthEndDate,0),(DT_DATE)"1960-01-01")
```

You won't need the first REPLACENULL anymore since we now handle it before the calculations.

Therefore:

```
DATEADD("d",REPLACENULL((DT_I8)AuthEndDate,0),(DT_DATE)"1960-01-01")
```

Edit: You can change the 0 to whatever you want the NULL to become, 0 was a placeholder.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Please see my edit, try doing the replacenull and then the conversion. We should have done the replacenull first thing, my fault.